# In python, if ID matches, move row to column while summing specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have data with Spouses on separate rows, but each spouse shares the same ID. These IDs, in some cases, are on several rows. When IDs match, I need to move the spouse row to a column, so both spouses share one row. I will also then need to sum values.

Input

```
   ID  Position  Title  First  Last  SpTitle  SpFirst  SpLast  Address    Value1  Value2  Value3
0  456 HoH       Mr.    John   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN     123 street  10      NaN     30
1  456 Spouse    Mrs.   Jane   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN     123 street  10      NaN     30
2  789 HoH       Mrs.   Jane   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN     456 road    100     200     300
3  789 HoH       Mrs.   Jane   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN     456 road    400     500     600
4  789 Spouse    Mr.    John   Doe   NaN      NaN      NaN     456 road    NaN     10      30
```

Desired Output

```
   ID  Position  Title  First  Last  SpTitle  SpFirst  SpLast  Address    Value1  Value2  Value3
0  456 HoH       Mr.    John   Doe   Mrs.     Jane     Doe     123 street  20      NaN     60
1  789 HoH       Mrs.   Jane   Doe   Mr.      John     Doe     456 road    500     710     930
```

There are thousands of rows. Some IDs are duplicated over dozens of rows. I think it would use `groupby` and `agg`, but I can't seem to get it working correctly.

When an ID matches, how can I move the spouse to share the same row as the Head of household (HoH) while summing values?

Here is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Combine sheets
df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel("C:/Users/Sheet.xlsx", sheet_name=None), ignore_index=True)

# Drop blank IDs
df = df[df['ID'].notna()]

# Insert Spouse columns
df.insert(loc = 10, column='SpTitle', value = '')
df.insert(loc = 11, column='SpFirstName', value = '')
df.insert(loc = 12, column='SpMiddleName', value = '')
df.insert(loc = 13, column='SpLastname', value = '')
df.insert(loc = 14, column='SpBirthDate', value = '')
df.insert(loc = 15, column='SpGender', value = '')

m = df.Position.eq("Spouse")

df.loc[m, ["SpTitle", "SpFirstName", "SpMiddleName", "SpLastName", "SpBirthDate", "SpGender" ]] = df.loc[
    m, ["Title", "First Name", "Middle Name", "Last Name", "Gender", "Date of Birth"]
].values

df[["Value 2019", "Value 2020", "Value 2021", "Value 2022", "Fund 2019", "Fund 2020", "Fund 2022", "Fund 2021"]] = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False)[
    ["Value  2019", "Value 2020", "Value 2021", "Value 2022", "Fund 2019", "Fund 2020", "Fund 2022", "Fund 2021"]
].transform(np.sum, min_count=1)

df[["SpTitle", "SpFirstName", "SpMiddleName", "SpLastName", "SpBirthDate", "SpGender"]] = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False)[
    ["SpTitle", "SpFirstName", "SpMiddleName", "SpLastName", "SpBirthDate", "SpGender"]
].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())

df = df[~m].drop_duplicates()

df.to_csv("C:/Users/data.csv", index = False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do different aggregations on your columns after a groupby on `ID` and in the end you fill the values for rows with `spouses` into the aggregated output.

```
df = df.set_index('ID')
spouses = df.loc[df['Position'].eq('Spouse'), ['Title', 'First', 'Last']].values
agg_dict = {col : 'sum' if col in ['Value1', 'Value2', 'Value3'] else 'first' for col in df.columns.tolist()}

out = df.groupby(level=0).agg(agg_dict).reset_index()
out.loc[:, ['SpTitle', 'SpFirst', 'SpLast']] = spouses

print(out)
```

Output:

```
    ID Position Title First Last SpTitle SpFirst SpLast     Address  Value1  Value2  Value3
0  456      HoH   Mr.  John  Doe    Mrs.    Jane    Doe  123 street    20.0     0.0      60
1  789      HoH  Mrs.  Jane  Doe     Mr.    John    Doe    456 road   500.0   710.0     930
```

Comment: This line ```out.loc[:, ['SpTitle', 'SpFirst', 'SpLast']] = spouses``` Gives the error ```ValueError: Length of values (2830) does not match length of index (1328)```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
m = df.Position.eq("Spouse")

df.loc[m, ["SpTitle", "SpFirst", "SpLast"]] = df.loc[
    m, ["Title", "First", "Last"]
].values

df[["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]] = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False)[
    ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"]
].transform(np.sum, min_count=1)

df[["SpTitle", "SpFirst", "SpLast"]] = df.groupby("ID", as_index=False)[
    ["SpTitle", "SpFirst", "SpLast"]
].transform(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())

df = df[~m].drop_duplicates()

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    ID Position Title First Last SpTitle SpFirst SpLast     Address  Value1  Value2  Value3
0  456      HoH   Mr.  John  Doe    Mrs.    Jane    Doe  123 street    20.0     NaN    60.0
2  789      HoH  Mrs.  Jane  Doe     Mr.    John    Doe    456 road   500.0   710.0   930.0
```

Comment: This is combining the two rows, and summing values, but SpTile, SpFirst, and SpLast output blank.  Interestingly is is putting a column ```SpLastName2``` in the last column postion filled with the correct values. I have updated my question with my code as is.